# List of files in a certain directory that have a certain string in the name

Tags: python, directory

So I started python today and can't rly go through some chaos I encountered on the internet for this topic.

Many solutions a I try with `os.walk` and `glob` don't work - I of course assume that's because it's my first day and I just went through some basic function knowledge.

Anyway - I have for example a directory **X:\P4V** where I have my Perforce and I would like to go through this directory and print a list of all the files that have word '**GRAPH**' in the string.

I know it's basic sh*t but it srsly makes my head hurt.

Thx in advance, cheers.

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: what is your code? just `glob.glob("X:\P4V\*GRAPH*)` should be all you need. if you just need the name of the file, try `os.path.basename(<file_name>)`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, so.. first of all sry for not providing the code - my bad and second: I managed to finally do it just didn't understand the `os.walk` module correctly.

```
import os
path = "X:/P4V"

def search_for_file():
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
        for file in files:
            if file.endswith("GRAPH.uasset"):
                path_file = os.path.join(root, file)
                print(path_file)

search_for_file()
```

I wasn't able to fully understand the usage of `file` in `for file in files`.

Anyway, will try to write better questions from now on :)